# My current code copies tabs, but not data

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that will copy tabs from all the files in a folder and combine them into one workbook. I have a current code which will pull the tabs, but they come back blank. I need all the data from the original files to be combined into one file. Is anyone able to help me fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
Sub CreateSheet(worksheetname)
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = worksheetname
End With
End Sub


Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        CreateSheet (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name)

     Next I

  End Sub


Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents
Call WorksheetLoop
'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)


'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop


ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't copy the sheets anywhere in your code, only the sheet names, that's why the sheets are empty. Look into [Worksheet.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel)

Comment: I want my tabs to keep the same name, and they typically vary. This site simply calls the sheets "sheet 1" etc. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You're not copying sheets,  you're creating new ones with `.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = worksheetname`.  With what you're trying to do - will there be duplicate sheet names across all the files you're trying to copy from?

Comment: No, all sheet names are different

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson You can create a worksheet and name it on the same line or you can add a worksheet and set a variable reference to it on the same line - you just can't add a worksheet, rename it and set it to a variable on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `WorksheetLoop` procedure with the code below.  This will copy each sheet from the referenced (`OpenedBook`) workbook to `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop(OpenedBook As Workbook)

    Dim wrksht As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each wrksht In OpenedBook.Worksheets
            wrksht.Copy Before:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Next wrksht
    End With

End Sub
```

Change this line of code in the `LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder` procedure:

```
Call WorksheetLoop
```

to

```
WorksheetLoop wb
```

If the workbooks you're opening contain code in the open event you may need to add (I know there's a better way than this and I just can't think of it at the moment):

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a new sheet with a custom name, just the default name. But you *can* immediately rename it.

Try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    set NewSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)) 
    NewSheet.Name = worksheetname
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the parameters in the sub procedure and use the copy command.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop(WB As Workbook)

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer
     Dim myWB As Workbook

     Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = WB.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        'CreateSheet (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name)
        WB.Worksheets(I).Copy after:=myWB.Sheets(myWB.Sheets.Count)

     Next I

  End Sub


Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents
 WorksheetLoop WB
'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)


'Save and Close Workbook
  WB.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop


ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```